Solving bivariate polynomials
Is there any way to find the roots of a bivariate polynomial numerically, for example
$p(x,y) = 1.0y^3 + (-7.0x - 7.0)y^2 + (14.0x^2 + 28.0x + 14.0)y - 8.0x^3 - 24.0x^2 - 24.0x - 8.0$.
I have already searched a lot of StackOverflow and the internet and only found methods that work with systems of bivariate equations.
With solution, I mean for example $y = (4+4x)$, since $p(x,4+4x) = 0$
edit: I should have been more clear with my example, I am talking about a polynomial of arbitrary degree, not just $ \leq 4$
edit 2: I also know about the puiseux algorithm but I am specifically looking for an alternative that suits the real case without singularities.

Your polynomial is degree three in $y$, with coefficients functions of $x$. There is a formula for the solutions of polynomials of degree three, like the quadratic formula only much hairier. A websearch should turn up that formula for you.

In the general case Newton proposed the idea of guessing that y is a "generalized power series" in $x$ with undetermined coefficients (also called a Puiseux series). The new twist is  that in certain circumstances  you must expand $y(x)$ using integer powers of say $x^{1/5}$; ie, $y(x)=\sum_k c_k x^{k/5}$.   See e.g V.I. Arnold's little book Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke.

@GerryMyerson Hey Gerry, i am sorry I should have been more clear with my example. I meant polynomials of arbitrary degree

@MathFont Thank you for the reference, I know about the Puiseux algorithm, I am specifically thinking about the case when we do not have singularities and therefore do not need Puiseux expansions. Additionally I have read that the puiseux algorithm does not really suit the case where we have real coefficients
